# UFD with Windows PE requires HDD Drivers to see local drives

Tags: windows, windows-pe

hi I'm attempting to image a machine, but after following the instuctions listed on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee523217(v=ws.10).aspx I have hit a problem. The reference computer requires drivers to access the local HDD's. Does anyone know how I can add my drivers to the WinPE bootable Flash Drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to mount the actual WIM to add drivers.

```
Dism /Mount-Wim /WimFile:C:\test\images\Your.wim /MountDir:C:\test\offline
```

Once your WIM is mounted, you can add drivers with Dism.  I usually have a whole subdirectory worth of drivers, which you can add all at once.

```
Dism /Image:C:\test\offline /Add-Driver /Driver:c:\drivers /Recurse /ForceUnsigned
```

Then you need to save the changes...

```
Dism /Unmount-Wim /MountDir:C:\test\offline /Commit
```

...and copy the new WIM to the flash drive (which you've apparently done before, based on your link).  For more information, there's [a TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744355%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Your comments were correct, but I think still assume some prior knowledge. It was the link to the  TechNet article that really got me across this issue. thanks for all the info.